# Error "cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement"

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, postgresql-8.4

Using PHP 5.3.3, PostgreSQL 8.4.11, pgbouncer 1.3.4 (in `session` mode) on CentOS 6.2 I'm trying to execute several SQL commands and fetch the results by a PHP script.

When I copy the commands from script to *psql* prompt they work flawlessly and return 12 rows:

[image]

But when I run from script I get the error:

```
SQLSTATE[42601]: Syntax error: 7 ERROR: cannot insert multiple commands into a prepared statement
```

Any help please?

Below is my failing PHP code, I tried using `$db->query()` instead of `$db->prepare/execute` too:

```
try {
        $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $db = new PDO(sprintf('pgsql:host=%s port=%u; dbname=%s',
                DBHOST, DBPORT, DBNAME), DBUSER, DBPASS, $options);

        $sth = $db->prepare("
            start transaction;
            create temporary table temp_ids (id varchar not null) on commit drop;
            insert into temp_ids (id)
                    select id
                    from pref_money
                    where yw = to_char(current_timestamp - interval '1 week', 'IYYY-IW')
                    order by money
                    desc limit 10;

            create temporary table temp_rids (rid integer not null) on commit drop;
            insert into temp_rids (rid)
                    select rid
                    from pref_cards
                    where stamp > now() - interval '1 day' and
                    id in (select id from temp_ids) and
                    bid = 'Мизер' and
                    trix > 0;

            SELECT r.rid, r.cards, to_char(r.stamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as day,
                    c.bid, c.trix, c.pos, c.money, c.last_ip, c.quit,
                    u.id, u.first_name, u.avatar, u.female, u.city, u.vip > CURRENT_DATE as vip
                    FROM pref_rounds r, pref_cards c, pref_users u
                    WHERE u.id = c.id and
                        r.rid = c.rid and
                        r.rid in (select rid from temp_rids)
                    order by rid, pos;
            commit;
        ");
        $sth->execute();
        while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
              # stuff a JSON object
        }
} catch (Exception $e) {
        exit('Database problem: ' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got a tip at the mailing list to get rid of the temp. tables and it works for me:

```
select r.rid, r.cards, to_char(r.stamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as day,
    c.bid, c.trix, c.pos, c.money, c.last_ip, c.quit,
    u.id, u.first_name, u.avatar, u.female, u.city, u.vip > CURRENT_DATE as vip
    from pref_rounds r, pref_cards c, pref_users u
    where u.id = c.id and
    r.rid = c.rid and
    r.rid in (
        select rid
            from pref_cards
            where stamp > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1 day' and
            id in (
                select id
                    from pref_money
                    where yw = to_char(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - interval '1 week', 'IYYY-IW')
                    order by money
                    desc limit 10) and
                   bid = 'Misere' and
                   trix > 0
    )
    order by r.rid, c.pos
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this, begin a transaction and split your querys up, as your not inserting values from user input there is no need to prepare the query, also as your not expecting a result from any but the last one exec is fine. on the last one you can use query(). If an exception occurs then you can rollback the changes.

```
<?php 
try {
    $options = array(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $db = new PDO(sprintf('pgsql:host=%s port=%u; dbname=%s',
    DBHOST, DBPORT, DBNAME), DBUSER, DBPASS, $options);
    //Transaction
    $db->beginTransaction();

    $db->exec("create temporary table temp_ids (id varchar not null) on commit drop;");

    $db->exec("insert into temp_ids (id)
                    select id
                    from pref_money
                    where yw = to_char(current_timestamp - interval '1 week', 'IYYY-IW')
                    order by money
                    desc limit 10;");

    $db->exec("create temporary table temp_rids (rid integer not null) on commit drop;");

    $db->exec("insert into temp_rids (rid)
                    select rid
                    from pref_cards
                    where stamp > now() - interval '1 day' and
                    id in (select id from temp_ids) and
                    bid = 'Мизер' and
                    trix > 0;");
    //Commit changes before doing your select
    $db->commit();

    $sth = $db->query("SELECT r.rid, r.cards, to_char(r.stamp, 'DD.MM.YYYY HH24:MI') as day,
                    c.bid, c.trix, c.pos, c.money, c.last_ip, c.quit,
                    u.id, u.first_name, u.avatar, u.female, u.city, u.vip > CURRENT_DATE as vip
                    FROM pref_rounds r, pref_cards c, pref_users u
                    WHERE u.id = c.id and
                        r.rid = c.rid and
                        r.rid in (select rid from temp_rids)
                    order by rid, pos;");


    while ($row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)) {
        # stuff a JSON object
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    //Transaction rollback
    $db->rollback();
    exit('Database problem: ' . $e->getMessage());
}

?>
```

Comment: I get the error: `Undefined table: 7 ERROR: relation "temp_rids" does not exist LINE 7: r.rid in (select rid from temp_rids)` (even if I disable the pgbouncer).